# rearrange positive and negative numbers php

Tags: php

An array has negative and positive numbers. Separate the numbers such that negative numbers are at the beginning and positive numbers at the end without changing the order.

> Example:
>
> **Array = {1, -3, -5, 9 , -8}**
>
> **O/P = {-3, -5, -8, 1, 9}**

I found many answer in c , c++ , java but not in  PHP , so can any one please let me know how or better way to achieve this?

> **However this question put on hold , i tried with some of solutions and**
>   **find my own answer added below , hope it might be useful for someone.**

```
function part($arr){

    $j = 0;

    for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){

       $val = $arr[$i];
       $k = $i;

      while($k>$j && $val < 0){

         $arr[$k] = $arr[$k-1];
         $k = $k-1;

         if($j==$k){
           $j=$j+1;
         }

        $arr[$k] = $val;

      }

    }

    return $arr;

  }

  $arr = array(1, -3, -5, 9 , -8);
  print_r(part($arr));
```

Comment: If you show us the code you've already tried to write, we might be able to better help you.

Comment: I am making code as of now , and tried to convert some solution that i found in c or c++ (other code language)

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you...

Comment: There is one interesting site about PHP - http://php.net/ - you could consider visiting it

Comment: Thanx Marc B & Marcin for your great help.

Comment: @MarcB: Added my code. Thanx for your comment

Answer (score 2):

Without doing all the work for you.

Look into `array_filter` you could filter the negative values into 1 array, then filter the positive values into another array.

Then use `array_merge` to merge the 2.